# Was ist "XFT standard" for a web service?

Tags: web-services

I'm confronted with a web service for which the documentation states the web service is

> based on the XFT standard

There is one further mention that the request is sent as POST using a given parameter name (which makes it sound like application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

The only reference to "XFT" I can find relates to SAP (something about an XFT document connector) and xft.com. Can anyone shed any light on what an "XFT standard" for a web service would be?

Answer (score 0):

In my context, XFT stands for "eXchange For Travel", a niche XML standard defined by http://exchangefortravel.org/. From the website it seems activity has ceased in 2018.

Technically, the interface is an XML POST using multipart/form-data with a single parameter.